# Defining variables in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, types

I need to have `dataXHip[frameNum]` be a number rather than `undefined`.
I've declared it as

```
dataXHip = [];
```

Then, I set a value as:

```
dataXHip[frameNum] = Number(dataX[frameNum]);
```

However, using the "oftype" function, I learn that `dataXHip[frameNum]` is `undefined`.

Comment: What you stated doesn't make any sense...`dataXHip[frameNum] = Number(dataX[frameNum]);`. `dataXHip[frameNum] ` needs to have a value in the first place.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve..?

Comment: `Number(dataX[frameNum])` is undefined then, although it should at least show up as NaN, as such being of type `number`.

Comment: I think OP is assuming incorrectly that you need to define the object type ahead of time. JavaScript is a dynamically typed language.

Comment: This question is very poorly phrased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `typeof` should work the way you expect.

An example:

```
> data = []
> data[2] = 15
> console.log(typeof(data[2]));
number
```

If this is not what you are trying to do, you should try to make your question more clear.